# Flask is running Python2 but I need python3

Tags: python

I'm using Kali Linux. I wanted to make the default version of python to python3. Now it is python2. Both version(python2.7 & python3.6) is already installed.

I couldn't find a way to do this. I ended up searching when someone said I shouldn't change the default version

I figured out flask isn't running python 3.6+ cause it couldn't recognize f-strings which was introduced in python 3.6. I thought maybe changing the default version of python can help me. Now I'm confused.

I want to run flask apps with python 3.6+ or the latest versions. How do I do it? I ran into some of the similar questions but those couldn't help.

Comment: Any serious Python development should use [Virtual Environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: [Link 1](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html)
or
[Link 2](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/linux/)

Use these articles to install python 3.6+.

Comment: Yes. That would be good. But I wanted to know how to do it without of virtualization. @RayToal

Comment: @ShashankSingh python 3.6 is already installed by default.

Comment: Use `python3 file.py` instead of `python file.py`

Comment: I know I can do this. But the question is about flask. How can specify python version while running "flask run"?

Comment: If you want to (1) leave Python 2 as your system default Python, (2) avoid virtual environments, and (3) run your app with `flask run`, I don't have any idea. Maybe someone else can help. Doing `flask run` within a virtual env made with Python 3 will definitely work; I do that all the time. I'm not sure your three requirements can work together, but never say never. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `pip` with Pyhton 3:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install flask
```

It will do the job for the rightful version of Python.

And always invoke your script with `python3` to be sure you are using the proper version. You can also check with `which` command to understand what binary will be executed when invoking in shell:

```
jlandercy@themis:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
jlandercy@themis:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Or create an [alias](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux) to python3 if you find it easier, then `which` will respond accordingly.